# Old story about some guy being able to manipulate radio waves

Tags: story-identification

I read a story about some guy that was able to manipulate radio waves and turn inanimate objects to life. He was stopped when he was driven into a tunnel underground or under a river that was able to block the waves. A previous attempt to put him in a radio shielded truck failed because the truck couldn't block the long waves that were actually doing it.
Thanks,
Isaac

Comment: Was it a novel or a short story? Did you read it online or in a book? How old is the story, how long ago did you read it? Was there any connection between the guy's two weird powers, how power to "manipulate radio waves" and his power to "turn inanimate objects to life"?

Comment: Short story. Read it in a soft cover compilation of like 8 short stories.  Read it like 15 years ago but it may have been a lot older then that.  It had a picture of a rust red or red freighter (square and bulky)space ship over flying a forest.

Comment: You should edit that information into your question. Comments can be deleted.